# DV1000 Wireless Dosent Seem To Work

Tags: wireless, networking

The wireless driver on my hp DV1000 does not work on ubuntu 11.10.

source DV1000 LINUX

I need the drivers so that then i can update to the newest ubuntu it says firmware missing and i seriously dont know were to get it.

for the wireless card i have a broadcom corportation BCM4306 802.11B/G WIRELESS LAN CONTROLLER

Comment: Please post the wireless card details from the terminal command: lspci -nn.

Comment: for the wireless card i have a broadcom corportation BCM4306 802.11B/G WIRELESS LAN CONTROLLER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4306 comes in two versions, and they take different drivers, so since you didn't post the output of the requested lspci -nn, you need to determine if the chip is version 2 with the pcid of 14e4:4306 or is version 3 with 14e4:4307.  The version 3 works with the b43 driver and the version 2 with the b43legacy driver.  Both drivers need firmware, which may be installed via a package install.
The proprietary firmware cannot be distributed with the release,so you
have to manually add it. Use a wired connection, and in a terminal:

```
   sudo apt-get update  
   sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
```

and accept the offer to download the Broadcom files, which
will put the Broadcom firmware into /lib/firmware/b43.
If you don't get the offer to download, then purge the package
and try again:

```
   sudo apt-get purge b43-fwcutter  
   sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
```

If you have the version 2, you might have to blacklist the b43 driver, which you may do by appending "blacklist b43" to the end of the /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf file.
Ensure you have not activated any of the other drivers like the wl (STA) driver by activating them through "additonal drivers".